# Requesting an Uber ride with Apple Pay as a payment method

Tags: uber-api

Is there a way to request an Uber ride through the rest API with Apple pay as the payment method?

Currently, setting Apple Pay (`payment_method_id`, https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/payment-methods-get) when requesting the ride fails.

Is there a way to access a web view hosted by Uber that would allow the user to authorize the payment through Touch ID and use Apple pay?

Comment: To be clear, you are saying you are calling payment-methods-get for a user and seeing Apple Pay as one of the available payment methods for that user? "The Payment Methods endpoint allows retrieving the list of the user’s available payment methods." If you see apple_pay as available for that user, you should not get an error when you specify that payment method for that user via post /requests. (https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post) Can you add details of that failure response if that is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: That's right. I'm showing the user their payment options, but using apple_pay fails whereas selecting any other credit card option works. I'll have access to the response logs tomorrow and add them to the issue

Comment: Sorry, again, just to be absolutely clear, you are not adding apple_pay as a method (as possibly implied by you saying you want to authorize users to use the payment) but apple_pay is already an option you see for that individual user?

Comment: Apologies, ignore my comments. I see the issue now. Will work on an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

confirmed that apple_pay is not available to be used as a payment method through the API when posting a request.

In terms of your question "Is there a way to access a web view hosted by Uber that would allow the user to authorize the payment through Touch ID and use Apple pay?" - No, this is not an option.

It is true that apple_pay (and android_pay) can be a payment method for a user's account and thus you could argue should be returned in get-payment-methods. However as it cannot be used in the API it perhaps should be filtered. Uber API team will look into possible solutions here. Thanks and hope this was helpful!

Comment: Are there any other payment methods that should not be used when posting a request? Should we limit the methods we use to credit cards only?

Comment: Android Pay is similar to Apple Pay (in that the phone manufacturers require extra control specific to their device to pay, which is hard for an API). I do not have any other specific payment methods to mark for you, but did file a ticket internally to see if there is further documentation or filtering we might want to do here. No ETA on any action there, however. Thanks.